# New coordinates, after x ms

Tags: math, coordinates, distance

I have 2 coordinates, the source, and the destination. I can calculate the distance between the two points, but I have to know at which coordinates something that's walking from source to destination is, after some time has passed, given a specific walk speed (units/ms). What would be the best way to do this?

This is most likely a simple problem, but it's hard to search for it, seeing how I don't know the exact mathematical terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a point A (source) with coordinates (Xa, Ya) and a point B (Xb,Yb) the destination, the distance betwwen them is

Da,b = Sqrt((Xa-Xb)^2 + (Ya-Yb)^2)

*Sqrt = square root

After t seconds the moving object,(it moves at U speed) will be at the point T (Xt, Yt).
The distance from the source is

Da,t = U*t

The coordinates of point T are

Xt = Xa + (Xb - Xa)*Dat/Dab

Yt = Ya + (Yb - Ya)*Dat/Dab

Comment: Works, thanks! Although I have to use Xt = min(Xa, Xb) + (max(Xa, Xb) - min(Xa, Xb)) [...] in my application, and I'm not sure why... regardless, it does what it's supposed to do :)